ASP.Net Webform: Server side web method not firing by jquery ajax
I am working with web form where i have button and one input file. when user click on a button then file open dialog will open and user select file. user selected file will be pass to server side function. basically i am uploading file to server side using jQuery ajax.
i am using jQuery ajax to call my server side function but server side function is not calling and my JavaScript throwing undefined error. for long time i stuck with the scenario and not able to understand where i made the mistake.
please see my code and tell me what to rectify my code.
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnImport").click(function (e) {
                alert('Hello');
                $("#fileInput").click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $("#fileInput").change(function (e) {
                alert('ajax fire');
                var files = e.target.files;
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    var file = files[0];
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('fileName', file.name);
                    formData.append('fileContent', file);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/FrmSubProject.aspx/ImportPointsData',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d); // Assuming the response is JSON
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Error occurred while uploading the file.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

[WebMethod]
public static string ImportPointsData(string fileName, byte[] fileContent)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileContent);
    return "File uploaded successfully!";
}       

Please drive me to right direction with your valuable time. Thanks
